# Window resize is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have made a markup for Q&A quiz.

When I try to resize the window, I got invalid value for both height and width. For example: on mobile viewport i got the following values `height: 9428992px; width: 880px;` !!!!?

Here is how I get document height and width:

```
$.getDocHeight = function(){
 var D = document;
 return Math.max(
  Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
  Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
  Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
 );
};

$.getDocWidth = function(){
 var D = document;
 return Math.max(
  Math.max(D.body.scrollWidth, D.documentElement.scrollWidth),
  Math.max(D.body.offsetWidth, D.documentElement.offsetWidth),
  Math.max(D.body.clientWidth, D.documentElement.clientWidth)
 );
};
```

All html, css and jQuery code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5nuw4h02/) to save room at SO.

I'm not sure why it's behaving this way. Is it my CSS or HTML structure?!!!
Also I found `<section class="bottom row">....</section` filled the lower part till the end of window, but it's size exceeded the visible window (Terms and Condition part is not showing).

I don't know if better html structure would fix this JS issue!

I'd appreciate your help!

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish, maybe my structure or style are not correct.

User expect to open the page and see first section fills the screen. Red part fills the top then the blue fills the rest of the 'window/page'. So user should see all context start from top image and ends with 'Terms and Condition' at the right lower corner.

When user clicks on 'START QUIZ', `<div class="section">...` should animate to the top and `<div id="section-1">..` would replace it.

After that, when user click on 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' window should animate to right section to see `<class class="answer">` part for more details. Which it has a 'NEXT' button. When user clicks on it the window should animate up to show a new section '....'.

And so on. This is the whole idea. Hope this explains the flow of every part.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling `$(document).ready(sizeUpdate);` and `$(window).resize(sizeUpdate);` at the bottom?

Comment: @Snorlax I'm calling them n order to be ready before resizing the browser window.

Comment: But you already have everything wrapped inside a `document.ready()`. Why not just do `sizeUpdate()` at the bottom?

Comment: @Snorlax I tried it and it's not working. Window doesn't get updated or change it's value when I resize the browser.

Comment: The issue lies upon your `$(".section").css("height", widnowHeight);` and `$(".section").css("width", widnowWidth);` part. I'm not sure why it does that, but that's the one screwing you up.

Comment: @Snorlax. I guess it's the cause. I removed '<div class="section">' content and still get same weird behaviour. Is there any better way to write this JS file and get Window Height?

Comment: May I ask... Why aren't you doing this with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

First remove the unnecessary semicolons you have used

```
function sizeUpdate(){
        widnowHeight = $.getDocHeight();
        widnowWidth  = $.getDocWidth();
        $('#value').html(widnowHeight);

        $(".section").css("height", widnowHeight);
        $(".section").css("width", widnowWidth);

        if (selected_section == 2){
          $("#section-1").css("margin-top", widnowHeight*-1);
          $("#section-1").css("margin-left", widnowWidth*-1);
        };//Semicolon not required

        if (selected_section == 3) {
          $("#section-1").css("margin-top", widnowHeight*-1);
          $("#section-2").css("margin-top", widnowHeight*-1);

          $("#section-1").css("margin-left", widnowWidth*-1);
          $("#section-2").css("margin-left", widnowWidth*-1);
        };//Semicolon not required

        if (selected_section == 4) {
          $("#section-1").css("margin-top", widnowHeight*-1);
          $("#section-2").css("margin-top", widnowHeight*-1);
          $("#section-3").css("margin-top", widnowHeight*-1);

          $("#section-1").css("margin-left", widnowWidth*-1);
          $("#section-2").css("margin-left", widnowWidth*-1);
          $("#section-3").css("margin-left", widnowWidth*-1);
        };//Semicolon not required
      };//Semicolon not required
```

And here is the code just check it it seems working fine http://jsbin.com/yesenutoki/1/edit?html,css,js

Comment: I suspect JSFiddle of running $(function() more than once. When I copy my test code from JSFiddle into your JSBin, it works perfectly... Well, the height returns 2500 or so... Which is wrong.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what exactly the issue is and what is your expected output. Because in your code you are using Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight)
Which will return you the height of the document and not the window.

Comment: @Manish. I use sublime as an editor. When I open the code in Chrome, and resize the window while inspecting the <div class="section".......> I can see the inline hight is increasing while I'm changing the width only; and it's value it so big like so [height: 33554432px; width: 699px;]. That doesn't make any sense. And I don't understand WHY? I expect correct height and width value on (window resize), right? That's for sure effect the whole quiz flow and other html elements positions.

Comment: Using a sublime editor is no issue. And even i tried to inspect the  <div class="section".......> in chrome the inline height is being shown as 548px when i'm trying it with the JSbin demo but when trying with JSfiddle its showing some 1444445px. In your CSS you have set the height as 100% so the division will adjust its height according to the window size. This is something even i'm not able to understand why is it happening.

Comment: @Manish. I know Sublime or other editors are not the issue, just sharing my environment. I got this crazy height number regardless where I'm testing it. I don't have any specified height except 2 divs within 'bottom' div. All height are set to 100% or auto for responsiveness.  I'm puzzled as well!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
    <p>Try resizing this browser window to trigger the "resize" event handler.</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = window.innerWidth+"    "+window.innerHeight;;
    });
    </script>
```

when you resize window it will give you current screen width and height.Try it